# How do I use insecure docker registries with Amazon EC2 Container Service (ECS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

We use a Docker registry inside our AWS VPC that is not accessible externally. We want to be able to launch tasks in ECS from this registry, however we see that the service is only ever at a PENDING state because the Docker daemon isn't able to access the registry.

I have found a sort of workaround by changing the launch configuration's user data but it doesn't feel like I'm doing this the best way:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=MY_CLUSTER_NAME >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo OPTIONS=--insecure-registry=insecure.registry.hostname:5000 > /etc/sysconfig/docker
service docker restart
docker start ecs-agent
```

This works perfectly, and I can see my task is running as expected. I just don't think this is necessarily the best way to do it.

AWS pointed me towards [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-container-service-ecs-update-access-private-docker-repos-mount-volumes-in-containers/) article which discusses authenticating with private registries, but I'm not looking to authenticate, just to have Docker ignore the fact that I'm using an insecure (ie not HTTPS) registry.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've spoken further with AWS and have the following solution:

You can do something like set docker options (including `--insecure-registry`) with a user-data script that executes on boot.  For example, `--insecure-registry` can be set with a script like the following:

```
#cloud-config
bootcmd:
 - cloud-init-per instance $(echo "OPTIONS=\"--insecure-registry=hostname:5000\"" > /etc/sysconfig/docker)
```

This way avoids the previous solution by not having the docker restart.

Regarding the insecure method, if we use a self-signed cert we can leverage this by either adding the certificate to the system CA trust store or to Docker's special trust store.

On the Amazon Linux AMI and ECS-optimized AMI, the system CA trust store is either located at `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source` or `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors` (depending on the format, see `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/README` for details) and you will need to run the `update-ca-trust` command after adding the certificate.  Docker's documentation on insecure registries provides more detail on this:

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#insecure-registries 
https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/sources/articles/certificates.md

I hope that also helps other people

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but how are you passing a cloud-init script to your beanstalk app?

Comment: You need to adjust the `User Data` for the launch config in the EC2 console. You can't actually edit the launch config, you need to create a copy and `Edit details`. In there, click the `Advanced Details` menu and you can see the `User Data` input. Edit it there, save the config, then go to the `Auto Scaling Group`, edit the `Details` tab and select the new `Launch Configuration` at the top

Comment: I'm trying to use an insecure server and use the docker option, but I've got a problem with Beanstalk overriding this OPTION change. The docker config gets modified, but this is what I end up with:

`OPTIONS="--insecure-registry=****.com:5000"`
`# Elastic Beanstalk`
`if [ -f /etc/elasticbeanstalk/set-ulimit.sh ]; then`
` . /etc/elasticbeanstalk/set-ulimit.sh`
`fi`

`# we already took care of the ulimit settings, setting these two variables to blank`
`# so the init.d script doesn't override our changes`
`OPTIONS=`
`DAEMON_MAXFILES=`

`other_args="-r=false"`

Any ideas how to modify later on?